# Python Importing data with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, how can I import data that looks like this:

```
waveform    [0] 
t0  26/11/2014  10:53:03.639218 
delta t 2.000000E-5 

time[0] Y[0]
26/11/2014  10:53:03.639218 1.700977E-2
26/11/2014  10:53:03.639238 2.835937E-4
26/11/2014  10:53:03.639258 2.835937E-4
26/11/2014  10:53:03.639278 -8.079492E-3
```

There are two delimiters, `:` and white space. I want to get rid of the date `24/11/2014` and delete the semicolons so that the `time` array looks like `105303.639218`, etc. So is there a way to specify two delimiters in the code, or is there a better way to analyse the data?

So far I have got:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_, time, y = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=':', skiprows=5)
plt.plot(time,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In a very general sense, use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: If it is in a string, you can use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass it the delimiters, then concatonate the list of strings returned to look how you like

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
time = '10:34:20.454068'
list_ = time.split(':')
''.join(list_)

# '103420.454068'
```

for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's sort of a roundabout way of doing this, but...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydata = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype='string', skiprows=5)

time = mydata[:,1]
time = np.array([s.replace(':','') for s in time])

y = np.array(mydata[:,2])

plt.plot(time,y)

plt.show()
```